# "You may award your bounty in 23 hours"?

Tags: bug, bounty

I wanted to reward [a couple of answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104498/how-to-create-custom-3d-areas-at-runtime) I got, giving both of them a bounty.

So I "started a bounty", and picked the "reward an existing answer" option.

However, when I try to assign it, I get the "You may award your bounty in 23 hours" message.

I don't understand, I'm not requesting attention to this question, I'm trying to… you know, "reward an existing answer"? Why do I have to wait for that, it does make zero sense.

Comment: [Follow-up](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/cant-i-create-a-second-bounty-in-the-same-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for the whole SE network and the issue has already been discussed several times. A couple instances:

- [Should the 24-hour timeout apply to bounties awarded for “exemplary answer”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116072/278154)
- [Should we still have to wait the 24 hours if the Bounty reason is 'Reward Existing Answer'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212961/278154)

The rationale behind the waiting period is to avoid users from easily transferring rep to one another. E.g.: Suppose you have a buddy in the network that you'd like to give some extra rep so that he/she can unlock some privileges. If there was no time limit, one could easily transfer substantial amounts of rep in minutes. With the time cap, at least this can't be done systematically.

To sum up, this is unlikely to ever be changed, since it is more of a safety mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The wait also brings even more attention to that amazing answer. (There's a big blue *+100* tag next to it in the top questions list, and it goes in the *featured* tab.)

I've seen *reward an existing answer*-bounties cause so many upvotes to an otherwise underappreciated answer that the answerer netted more rep from votes than the bounty. That happened [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/72316/7804) if I remember correctly.