# Can't I create a second bounty in the same question?

Tags: bug, bounty

*I wanted to reward [a couple of answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104498/how-to-create-custom-3d-areas-at-runtime) I got, giving both of them a bounty.*

After encountering [a first problem](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/you-may-award-your-bounty-in-23-hours), now there's a new one: **the "start a new bounty" button is not there any more**. Is this another "intentional" behaviour to keep the paranoid SE admins happy? Does it ever come back, or for that question it's just permanently disabled?

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to create another bounty. I believe the two day timer resets after your first bounty and future bounties will have a higher minimum value: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit

Comment: @Byte56 could you convert it to an answer? BTW that sucks: if I can't award the same amount to both, it will be pointless.

Comment: Well, the first part is just a guess, and the second part: it's just the minimum value, so I believe the next minimum will be 100, which is what you want I think.

Comment: @Byte56 but the first minimum was already 100 _"If you are placing a bounty on a question you answered, your minimum spend is 100"_ Fun thing is that that rule prevents using bounties to gather upvotes, but actually this happens only because they won't allow to select it immediately… lesson: don't do messy things, or they will mess even more, cascade-style.